# Object-Oriented JavaScript Converter

Tags: javascript, object, converters

So I am working in a converter application powered by JavaScript, and right now I am trying to create a huge object with all the measures. But whenever I debug it, it's saying things like:

> ```
> Expected ';' and instead saw '.' (var units.length = {};)
> Expected '.' at column 1, not column 10 (var units.length = {};)
> Unexpected '.' (var units.length = {};)
> etc.
> ```

It's been a long time since I coded in JS, so I'm having some confusion with it, would appreciate any help, here's the code:

```
var units = {};
var units.length = {};
var units.time = {};
var units.mass = {};
var units.temperature = {};

//Starting with Length
units.length.meter = 1;
units.length.meters = 1;

units.length.inch = 0.0254;
units.length.inches = 0.0254;

units.length.foot = 0.3048;
units.length.feet = 0.3048;

units.length.yard = 0.9144;
units.length.yards = 0.9144;

units.length.mile = 1609.344;
units.length.miles = 1609.344;

...
```

Comment: `var units.length` is simply not valid JS. Drop the `var`, just like you did for `units.length.meter = 1;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only use `var` to declare variables, not to create properties of an existing object:

```js
var units = {};
units.length = {};
units.time = {};
units.mass = {};
units.temperature = {};

//Starting with Length
units.length.meter = 1;
units.length.meters = 1;

units.length.inch = 0.0254;
units.length.inches = 0.0254;

units.length.foot = 0.3048;
units.length.feet = 0.3048;

units.length.yard = 0.9144;
units.length.yards = 0.9144;

units.length.mile = 1609.344;
units.length.miles = 1609.344;
```

Also consider

```js
var units = {
    length: {
        meter: 1,
        meters: 1,
        inch: 0.0254,
        inches: 0.0254,
        foot: 0.3048,
        feet: 0.3048,
        yard: 0.9144,
        yards: 0.9144,
        mile: 1609.344,
        miles: 1609.344
    },
    time: {},
    mass: {},
    temperature: {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Ah, i ara que veig el teu nom, visca els catalans al StackOverflow ;D

Answer (score 2):

No `var` before attributes, only variables.

```
var units = {
    length: {},
    time: {},
    mass: {},
    temperature : {}
};
```

NB: length is reserved to array/string length, you should avoid to name an attribute like that. And you should use an extend method to avoid to repeat `units` and `units.length`.

```
var units = {
    length: {
        meter: 1,
        meters: 1,
        inch: 0.0254,
        inches: 0.0254 // ...
    },
    time: {},
    mass: {},
    temperature : {}
};
```